# Binded store not reflecting values after adding record in store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-classic

I want to do some manipulations in the formula based on the store. When `viewmodel` loads that formula is getting triggered and do the manipulations properly but when I add a record in store its not getting triggered.

I have created a fiddle representing the above behavior. You can find it [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/319q). On click of button a new record gets added to the store. So formula should get triggered but its not whereas fields defined in the data object of `viewmodel` are working fine.

On googling I found that this binding should be deep copy. So I tried that as well but it dint resolved the issue.

```
formulas: {
   firstTestStoreRecord: {
     bind: {
        bindTo: '{testStore}',
        deep: true
     },
     get: function(testStore) {
        return testStore.getAt(0);
     }
   }
}
```

Any idea how can it be achieved?

Comment: I believe you cannot bindTo a store. Maybe this thread will help you https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?295408-Binding-notify-problem-with-array-binding
To solve your issue, personally I would add a datachange listener on the store that sets 'firstStoreRecord' on the vm. And I would bind my formula to that.

Comment: I agree with @ground_call. Alternatively, you can manually update the storage bind in the view model

Comment: @ground_call You can, however it was added in 6.50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `datachanged` event on the store as binding doesnt work with store data update.

```
stores: {
  firstTestStoreRecord: {
    model: 'Common.model.firstTestRecord',
    autoLoad: false,
    listeners: {
      datachanged: () => {console.log('triggered')}
    }
}
```

Comment: The ability to deep bind into a store was added in 6.5 IIRC. If you switch your original fiddle over to that version you should be able to see it. Otherwise, you'll need to stick with something like this.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli yes i observed that, but was looking solution for 6.0 version.